# Connect to SOAP 1.1 With PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, request

i have a soap web services and i need to connect and get result from it in PHP
the request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Booking xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <myOrder>
        <FromDate>dateTime</FromDate>
        <ToDate>dateTime</ToDate>
        <Price>decimal</Price>
        <siteCommission>decimal</siteCommission>
        <HotelPriceIncentive>decimal</HotelPriceIncentive>
        <Count>int</Count>
        <PriceId>int</PriceId>
        <HotelId>int</HotelId>
        <Add_ID>int</Add_ID>
        <Create_net_booking>int</Create_net_booking>
        <OrderRooms>
          <ClOrderRooms>
            <capacityName>string</capacityName>
            <BaseTypeName>string</BaseTypeName>
            <RoomsTypeName>string</RoomsTypeName>
            <SessionId>string</SessionId>
            <AmountBruto>decimal</AmountBruto>
            <AmountNetto>decimal</AmountNetto>
            <Price>decimal</Price>
            <Count>int</Count>
            <BaseTypeId>int</BaseTypeId>
            <RoomTypeId>int</RoomTypeId>
            <Adults>int</Adults>
            <Child>int</Child>
            <Infants>int</Infants>
          </ClOrderRooms>
          <ClOrderRooms>
            <capacityName>string</capacityName>
            <BaseTypeName>string</BaseTypeName>
            <RoomsTypeName>string</RoomsTypeName>
            <SessionId>string</SessionId>
            <AmountBruto>decimal</AmountBruto>
            <AmountNetto>decimal</AmountNetto>
            <Price>decimal</Price>
            <Count>int</Count>
            <BaseTypeId>int</BaseTypeId>
            <RoomTypeId>int</RoomTypeId>
            <Adults>int</Adults>
            <Child>int</Child>
            <Infants>int</Infants>
          </ClOrderRooms>
        </OrderRooms>
        <GeneralAreaName>string</GeneralAreaName>
        <HotelName>string</HotelName>
        <GeneralAreaId>string</GeneralAreaId>
        <CancelBooking_Cancelled>boolean</CancelBooking_Cancelled>
        <CancelBooking_CancellationDays>int</CancelBooking_CancellationDays>
        <CancelBooking_Policy>string</CancelBooking_Policy>
        <SourcePrice>int</SourcePrice>
        <ExternalPriceID>int</ExternalPriceID>
        <CustomerPriceRemark>string</CustomerPriceRemark>
        <DocketId>int</DocketId>
        <FirstName>string</FirstName>
        <LastName>string</LastName>
        <Email>string</Email>
        <Tz>string</Tz>
        <PhoneNum>string</PhoneNum>
        <CellNumber>string</CellNumber>
        <Address>string</Address>
        <CreditCardNum>string</CreditCardNum>
        <Credit_Tashlumim>string</Credit_Tashlumim>
        <Credit_ExpMont>string</Credit_ExpMont>
        <Credit_ExpYear>string</Credit_ExpYear>
        <Credit_CVV>string</Credit_CVV>
        <Comments>string</Comments>
        <Travellers>
          <clTraveller>
            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
            <LastName>string</LastName>
            <Title>string</Title>
            <DateBirthday>string</DateBirthday>
          </clTraveller>
          <clTraveller>
            <FirstName>string</FirstName>
            <LastName>string</LastName>
            <Title>string</Title>
            <DateBirthday>string</DateBirthday>
          </clTraveller>
        </Travellers>
        <ConfigParam>
          <AmountMarkup>string</AmountMarkup>
          <APP_AgencyXmlBaseUrl>string</APP_AgencyXmlBaseUrl>
          <DocketType>string</DocketType>
          <SystemTypeId>int</SystemTypeId>
          <AgencyId>int</AgencyId>
          <UserName>string</UserName>
          <Password>string</Password>
          <SubSite>int</SubSite>
        </ConfigParam>
        <Result>
          <XmlAfterRegistration>string</XmlAfterRegistration>
          <DocketId>int</DocketId>
          <BUNDLE_ID>string</BUNDLE_ID>
          <Reserv_Num>
            <string>string</string>
            <string>string</string>
          </Reserv_Num>
        </Result>
      </myOrder>
    </Booking>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

i try with php soapclient but i don't relay know how to do that right.
the error i get is:
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://web14.agency2000.co.il/bytechws/pricessearch.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://web14.agency2000.co.il/bytechws/pricessearch.asmx?WSDL" in C:\xampp\htdocs\credit2000\booking.php:96 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\credit2000\booking.php(96): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://web14.a...', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\credit2000\booking.php(81): callData('Booking', Object(stdClass)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\credit2000\booking.php on line 96 
any help please???

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL URL you are using does not exist. Without the correct URL you will never succeed with the request. PHP needs the WSDL to create the proper data structure.

Comment: Well, I cannot access it, and YOUR PHP cannot access it, so it must be wrong for some reason. Can you access it in your browser?

Comment: Yes, that works. And you should use that URL as well for the SoapClient.

Comment: OK but how?? i dont know

Comment: Somewhere in your code or configuration, you use this URL with "https" in front, and this should be changed to "http".

Comment: if i use http i get: "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: Which page? If your browser tells you that, then it is due to another issue in your software, but the Soap call probably worked.

Comment: i need to connect to this soap, give him all the parameters that he need and get response.

Comment: I was assuming that. One usually does not make Soap calls just to waste time. But we are not getting closer to a solution. You have to investigate which problem exists now, and describe it in your question (probably a new question). I can't see any new information that helps me helping you.

Comment: OK Sven Thank you very much.
i will try to fix it someway.

Comment: now i can connect to the services but i can not pass the parameters 
to the web services, can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I consider this a new question you should ask. Add as much detail as you can on WHY your code fails. It's very inconvenient to go into details inside comments here.

Comment: new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18374126/passing-variables-to-soap-web-service-in-php